# Advection equation - Method of characterestics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, characteristics, parabolic-pde

We'll consider the following equation defined on $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and $t>0$:
$$y_t+y.y_x=0$$
with the initial condition:
$$y(x,0)=\mathbb{1_{(-\infty,0)}(x)}$$
I tired to solve this equation using Method of characterestics:

let us define : $a=1$ and $b=y$ and $c=0.$

then we have $dy/dx=dy/dt=0$ and $dx/dt=y$

since the derivative of $y$ are equals to $0$. then $y$ is constant.

then we'll have $x(t)=y(x(t),t).t+A$ ($A$, is a constant of integration)

then, $y(x(t),t)=(x(t)-A)/t$

I did not know how to use initial condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the inviscous Burger's equation.

You got the characteristic curves $x(t)=y_0t+x_0$ and $y(t)=y(x(t),t)=y_0$ along these curves. Given a point $(x,t)$, the characteristic curve it lies on satisfies $$y_0=y(x,t)=y(x-y_0\Delta t, t-\Delta t)=const.=y(x-y_0t,0)=f(x-y_0t),$$ where $y(x,0)=f(x)$ is the initial condition.

This is a non-linear equation that may have multiple solutions. In the given case, the possible values for $y_0$ are $0$ and $1$. So if $x-t<0$ there is a characteristic with slope $y_0=1$ going through $(x,t)$, and if $x\ge 0$ then a characteristic of slope $y_0=0$. As there is an overlap  for $t>0$, there will be a shock front. By Rankine-Hugoniot the curve of this front has slope $1/2$, so that 
$$
y(x,t)=\begin{cases}1,&x<t/2,\\0,&x\ge t/2.\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I did not understand why $y$ verifies such equality (it's a little bit confusion because sometimes you use $y(t) $ and sometimes $y(x,t)$ and $y_0$ please would you like to clarify

Comment: Because all points on the characteristic curve, from initial condition to shock, have the same value $y_0$ for $y$. And this value is at the same time the slope in $x(s)=x-(t-s)y_0$. But at $s=0$ we also know that $y_0=f(x(0))=f(x-ty_0)$, so one has to solve this implicit equation.

Comment: Yes, I agree now, it's all clear, but at the end why you mentioned Rankine-Hugoniot, can't we just solve the implicit equation ?

Comment: No, the method of characteristics only works in the region where you have exactly one characteristic per point. As soon as characteristics cross, you have to apply the shock treatment.